# Simple legend box below multiple TikZ pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, legend

I have three subfigures in a figure, each has three TikZ pictures inside and a caption. Now I would like to add a legend for all TikZ pictures together.

I searched through other posts and tried different solutions. However I couldn't find anything to make it work. The closest one I found, was the proposed matrix from this question: [TikZ picture: how to add a legend?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398647/tikz-picture-how-to-add-a-legend)

I used the matrix in the bottom right TikZ picture with labels without the nodes, since I don't have any symbols.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[c]{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\matrix [draw,below left] at (current bounding box.south east) {
  \node [label=right:R...ROBOT] {}; \\
  \node [label=right:G...GOAL] {}; \\
  \node [label=right:O...OBSTACLE] {}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In my case, this destroys the layout:

[image: tikz grid three by three with misplaced legend]

Comment: Please add the complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), from `\documentclass{}` to `\end{document}`, instead of the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the three `tikzpicture`s. Use `scope` if needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[c]{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid ++(4,4);
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (5,0) grid ++(4,4);
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (10,0) grid ++(4,4);

\matrix [draw,below left] at (current bounding box.south east) {
  \node [label=right:R...ROBOT] {}; \\
  \node [label=right:G...GOAL] {}; \\
  \node [label=right:O...OBSTACLE] {}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{c}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```