# How to add a legend to a Kiviat diagram with mutltiple lines? (tkz-kiviat)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-kiviat

I am trying to make Kiviat diagram with multiple lines similar to the example provided here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10503/7892

This is the example code:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[scale=1.25,label distance=.5cm,
        radial  = 5,
        gap     = 1,  
        lattice = 5]{McCabe,LOC,Live Variables,Halstead N,Variablenspanne}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue,mark=none,
               fill=blue!20,opacity=.5](3,3.5,3,3.5,3)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=darkgray,
               fill=green!20,opacity=.5](0.5,1,0.5,0.75,1) 
\tkzKiviatLine[ultra thick,mark=ball,
                 mark size=4pt,color =Maroon](2,3.75,1,1.5,2)    
\tkzKiviatGrad[prefix=,unity=100,suffix=\ \texteuro](1)  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: kiviat-example]

How can I add a legend to specify the meaning of each line+marker+filling combination?

I have found this, which almost seems like what I want, except that I don't know how to show lines+markers instead of nodes in the created legend:
[TikZ picture: how to add a legend?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398647/tikz-picture-how-to-add-a-legend)

Arrows with labels pointing to the lines might be another option, but seems more complicated and I am also not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Just so you know "This package has been taken temporarily out of circulation to give the author time to investigate some problems.". https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-kiviat

Comment: -so it might be difficult to get people to help